# Agenda key binding don't work

Tags: emacs

I'm tring to setup agenda in emacs.

In the file `.emacs` I have such configuration

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
```

but after <kbd>C-c a</kbd> I have message:

> The symbol definition is void: org-defvaralias

Please help in fix this problem.

EDIT 1.

Key binding looks ok - after <kbd>C-h k</kbd> I see

<kbd>C-c a</kbd> org-agenda

EDIT 2.

After <kbd>M-x org-agenda</kbd> result is

> The symbol definition is void: org-defvaralias

Regards Krzysiek

Comment: You mean "C-c a" or "C-a a"?

Comment: @abo-abo. I make typo. It should be "C-c a". I already correct it.

Comment: Try to update to the latest Emacs version.

Comment: @abo-abo At the beginning I did not believe it would help, but it actually worked. Thank you.